# Does the perl interpreter parse code line-by-line or all together?

Tags: perl, interpreter

According to my understanding of the perl interpreter, the code is first parsed into an opcode. This opcode graph is then interpreted during execution. I want to know if the parsing happens line-by-line or all together.

I have some code with an `exit` statement at the beginning, but when I run the script, perl reports an error that lies way below the `exit` statement. (The error is a missing semicolon.) If the perl interpreter works line-by-line how can it report an error that lies below the exit statement? Or is the error reported during the parsing stage?

Comment: You're asking a question about very low-level Perl. Why do you need to know this?

Comment: After reading the answers below, compare `perl -e'exit; if'` to `perl -e'BEGIN{exit} if'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *If the perl interpreter works line-by-line how can it report an error that lies below the exit statement? Or is the error reported during the parsing stage?*

The error in question was reported during the parsing/compilation stage. It would have been reported even if you had used `-c`. These are called "compile-time errors".

Some errors can't be detected at that stage. Those are called "runtime errors".

---

> *According to my understanding of the perl interpreter, the code is first parsed into an opcode. This opcode graph is then interpreted during execution. I want to know if the parsing happens line-by-line or all together.*

The file is compiled as a whole, then the compiled form is executed from the start. `BEGIN` and `use` statements deviate from this; they are executed immediately after they are compiled (i.e. before the rest of the file is compiled).

```
$ perl -e'
    BEGIN { print "Start of compilation.\n"; }
            print "Start of execution.\n";
    # ...
    BEGIN { print "End of compilation.\n"; }
            print "End of execution.\n";
'
Start of compilation.
End of compilation.
Start of execution.
End of execution.
```

Using `-c` causes Perl to exit before starting the execution. (`BEGIN` and `use` statements are still executed as normal.)

```
$ perl -c -e'
    print "This statement was executed.\n"
    my $x = 4;
    $x += 5;
    print "$x\n";
    BEGIN { print "This statement was compiled.\n"; }
'
This statement was compiled.
-e syntax OK
```

Here's what the compiled result resembles:

```
$ perl -MO=Concise,-exec -e'
    my $x = 4;
    $x += 5;
    print "$x\n";
'
1  <0> enter
2  <;> nextstate(main 1 -e:2) v:{
3  <$> const[IV 4] s
4  <0> padsv[$x:1,2] sRM*/LVINTRO
5  <2> sassign vKS/2
6  <;> nextstate(main 2 -e:3) v:{
7  <0> padsv[$x:1,2] sRM
8  <$> const[IV 5] s
9  <2> add[t2] vKS/2
a  <;> nextstate(main 2 -e:4) v:{
b  <0> pushmark s
c  <0> padsv[$x:1,2] s
d  <$> const[PV "\n"] s
e  <2> concat[t3] sK/2
f  <@> print vK
g  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC
-e syntax OK
```

Answer (score 2):

The great thing about Perl is that the compiler and interpreter work hand-in-hand. Compiled code can be executed part-way through the compilation process, and the interpreter can ask for code to be compiled at run time

In general a program is compiled character-by-character and then executed, but if the compiler encounters a `BEGIN` block (or a `use` statement, which works like a `BEGIN`) then the Perl interpreter is invoked to execute that block immediately before the rest of the program is compiled

Once the compiler reaches the end of the file, the code is executed by thge interpreter. But run time Perl may also use `eval` to invoke the compiler

If there is a fatal error anywhere in the main source file, like a missing semicolon, then the Perl compiler will report the error straight away, before the interpreter starts to execute the compiled code